# How do I render a pdf data into an actual pdf file? (Using PHP)

Tags: php, parsing, pdf, pdf-rendering

The return that I am getting is like the actual content of the pdf, but when I try to like just create a pdf file and paste this data on a text editor and just save it as a pdf, when I try to open it, it just says like the file cannot be opened.

Here is the sample data that I am trying to create the pdf file of:

```
%PDF-1.2
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Name /Im1
/Width 195
/Height 114
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/Length 27065
/Filter [/ASCII85Decode /FlateDecode]
>>
stream
8;Z,gH#-71)TI[R>H3E->-63kC9"#[HuOqQpQS50ind<:+n:mApBkAg0goK2+c%;h
CCELjp]hBc,j)'u:">P1>Fj@DSc,'sA`']Fl^i'C4`A($XM)?Uf&#l%TD*Wgf9l#E
"U,'791he`$O\i`n`*-B]$8LEc-O^KOI_re[CEa!0#R8No%(!OcW.Fl)&`:;1UW-N
90]]R,W!E"I:M/`G:R[WI>_#mNYrAKDr/,]%RddEh]=[l(g$YDe6LJNd`d2.UdMkP
V!j]Jp%07nJ5;3I6/s+-f:8?N#-"T$Ch*S,TV.q[#7g6i[_I1`mf!%Wg@b:5k7Wj/
a*Bsf-O'9hG5(_h)^)YVmhh6KNb)g7eu;Rq0JK_SmFpJi0YVu4<kGZCZ@;"ArtZ8&
Uc.WY09\jk$pen#g9ihUg)N;(psc9AIXZ`EVG+i#f\"hfbEckU32S\3U1p%//b[h@
G4u6/]JGSb1PR[gh5aV\+sS>+&Ej9#"Ea(eq8J7.X<@d"Sa=@R@`3kb'Y"k[N[\2s
MJMJ@kmX;]UT7J"*ZQ0TTgOSR2/3*s1\^=n6]ju*U,7Qrs7OY8nduNW5(*-u@)Uts
BP8f71htMgDPp3u#'qk)[((MZ1+T&dZC>s[EiGf&8hZ#@l'pBh/o<>7m"XI>@gI_a
0ekE0WGUCu2/Cb_4*I]Fpa-IE;RWm`ncu%RbY8(V"'DO!hnFMu,P<21Y@#%ZeZ)&+
6jPUWSN?h"4S:3uGY.!Jj/J/O[]WXkbqf)c,&?)MID't"RQ#.k[r,L"**d7*TY\?j
qqQs*#&%D.=6]"kpWLYXb=X."97Y'D+-X.S@Lst;.EQgd8/eXV:drpjm>T9`;0'Dm
m=X/IjQ'h\.#l.e/RH/=GuR`W'%F!cZadM)`XH%ZC`*iu!YeS2:?<$RcdlCg!m*dL
)!DMSXHd$@KP5jpfm'b9P2h5PZY.UQ1hd"Zj2R'7N]LI\IN;_*F6ARn1ihYJb9_AG
+d@AE8B);T=@,?kL(,)p%Bk3HfJ+itnNh2[Oca'7W[lVg2fBate$VKAnF1CZ62XRn
VlN^hnf7hoI3G]WSa.AP91=lo:/,Wcp%.@mWJc:b/7tD3@R_isW)4e*OW%=[GjsW@
<N6$J<B!@#[ccf8CAait/'enhWdd'Qm"f#>3d'H,M2V6'l\dHuTiNukP)+AL6CM"P
j$lpV0p=F=d^2-WN!$/!#t[GJ<GV+Uj+s:tY7O`0O2.PV:hIa*Zj>on7h^fb#7hmJ
n)'a6D:PX$@0l#!?bb1KJHH./C4(EA5_DD38se,^%bCrT'V+92rqq%H:d\*fC/t*9
!)Zr-UPKKdWkHrm+jhZ4S1kFK.(R%:"9eO9*7!3rlKZp##7hk$NG=l]:$CYRR$;ON
1nj]cJ9"1:=0>f%Op'DlA&`2urVQ=t%Yu:gW\>m.5o[NeXG.6-c?aZII/22MQntpJ
0!!:qrZ;(MK*,SFEB:MLP:,B)db;$?:OH<L?ifkTY[&eWP&$L[8P-1b#sDLqlX]M4
!%<$Xg-lj!nrP"^`$Go#Kp+.ins/A*VqglEEg[0,7un^R\aVO40i8>,daDf&66.;Y
U&6So/1_4R@q&mm4oe-6@i+ecnS>s<de$6X),Kd4*1g"%d>Qs(oeXDs(`7MV_?J?&
$7o$?h7In!gpqLgbX#Gc?+Rt!d@s&7%NIHTp?^5(9-Km[MlRJ\N:h^R_Mb5u(G5gn
pB'`^&6;\`)5fC4&a5IJRYohWl%B?V[#6E&lp`C#%"N<W`f6ZjFEDVk/mU`36kC:V
/"?q2&L0c,(W^STDVWT^>:,V(A)FP.gU>Y4<Jr!:4.Lmni,J,>3U%':6?7hfPq,qu
p?pbK,0$$,B0aeh0pI(Ib*BDq1*0_qI"Gl"kKcZ-M*V2^d\KIS@B]3WR#fj_DC^W9
@M+X<))<"*#p7(pPdu/8mQf:5F_aUHDV_l]D;#]$;-q\qOkS_%^f%.8k4Irh9D-_s
-Vr7&kg:k5IB#XH6Ym8jA&\q5dB6ceL(,(k7RdF_A,6Jki<.8dPETY)S2krim#)Z5
Y#qr<il$\S=0JK'JqWc9kfg/5[uA36((3M"9%&LY5u@u>WDf^0)9>c"/X!Zd;sZ99
I^BB7WDoi0[C"NF?q<fo]Rid%XPi#E`agolFm[lt1]d^[cmY"70=XCf5j5Hb^4AN&
Kgls3QNB*=/KZ^WA36Xt)`A6/\.!j`?qA7RNugI&#;mb"UB?s]$:[%8S'i'o7b+p:
E7Kj8o]ah5.Cen!!0IUgXHq,@La;s6H&S/\2fHPT(]oH3JI=CM&e\"^&fKaR4:rn!
P[Xq+0kN0%2mC(D_"[TtVgL6pbmBP)8P+:5,R_CfSVfkE[e'`U#tch]U.?OME8]!m
X]l#J6jtfBQ`$Z[4_`)+j.V>5#M8%3EQTb8ag7+@1q>jVDT(AKLC^dd6>\2aZ0at*
EY)3$$):"OG*d[qBaZPUbE*Nt#Dg;`="n&!`8aJc"TFL?PnGB^)`i)>E[!2(-X_/M
9>:oppI6+p;@1XXIu13g:4LAm2h?H1eQC,#YfN&rm*)R1IJS[W%1?t"[!"^m]RTq(
3+Qu$QLRe3P;TT5?oc,N[t8=PaO[7b+2B-IWTT7r3OSr>a'TPcp*jh:E6CKm'_<>[
Xg2[b+c0QP0f_R+'[iX_,sT/?^\ho*97ZYWg8f`$mI(qWmhn?9n1[&/F+\f3,F_-/
MN2Bd(*;;+AQ32]!,p7IMF$"JD43s_eu]V(!;p!NV/uR4m$tr="`-uug5V;qVUWZ.
;jkVXrRtW=RR09K.R/mTF)\![+hk-C9cE67,#J^`IEMK'Hh'7ar9q_2n=\KXg;gX;
=MI.sL*=R53UZ/BSu;e?;-@%)bXe]aS[=_g:CucDe#-!*mKkr8B\'7f`aOQae"68%
YN;t4Wcf79((*X-"lu.T=Y*HXB&a7hW*ol>)WY89b+Ls0b^?#`Se(9S@*I4Es4;8$
3M2[anN7P2Rl504VH%E7&;_K;b:b]J;3TAHgd3Ip0FEF%(#Vu=DI1W/m"5/]M'GKa
9*5A,5g8n+7Bn<FMi$&p0#ogmT9bdTl]^u5F:hNF>O@&cdjsK2'n?%8H(Res;82)Q
JA+7un?7]o/YcM-Bk>%OqJ^a28o&0U*ooKlSp6MZqO4.`Pt*rbqXc4_:?b=7V#$gI
0Fg5sn_>nZ(&5d91H9*DO.Hpe0TI,M9,L/@oYb[8,0Q)nj1qeu*<[gJY<6k#LpsSF
!%,pHle!Yj<WLnTa^.,V()7PSj0,I_r1T=QdQ47*9ZuYP2Jib,W5Xf8pk'PP/VL0:
obq,r]>.+MoZK030Rsj/6'[UrU1-]7D/4'n2_<iD[iu\;n2G4<FRnKaTk\^VUachT
:+138mmFN4/ERBpS39rmcS$iV0bPBE<#7US55j*YSN@W==:c;daOg0-/28l!qtBDm
euYQ>gTtN'A"HHU[X7adR^aS4NbmCSA]KfO)`MZi]6E_;6\e^F>ff>\9q"HfM&_ZV
l"Z35T8KUTjjEaUijkdiTqMmHqJ"46`J_ct+"t07SjnQJ?9J6gk,+4lMI<X%!a8!N
d%f!<V7h*[Qle)iWqf^BMim8>1EsILWG9r/8Z=/bq%m)I0aWu`__Qf[C,(6`:l?T$
YAQ$cJU(?&Qh!?%ZBoK(:Zpp%3;%9EO/aP#A7,+IS?cuY+D\cJj)E89$/uIsG:)uD
5sup)($4TLL>=o2f;_mM:L1OE$V2e^F,c*9leT2Ik09B(`W#i5QRl:V(^_9GG]<!"
XmcSLbaC9Mkg?0p9r(t(F=AlLG4"#Da,dQ7eZ)U`n8md<NK9-uWf2gmi]Reo5&<?8
%@X/7lT_K&$&k/")$XI`=_<4&L;b$<(79g/#D'/p"U0i](.T4-BN,ND9rLl)=uWJ2
#*ZJm@r**b/\s]G+gE2F`-jotCb!RG(!o9W<Dp5*7=j3+maq7j)$GrikN:p^F3f?%
n%@QT^0bX[99LTH;D#IlI%5)nMA<"/hGpUW"e87'ShREdVt"J\U=P]]n\l<p;r"e7
[^lE_CB$Bmc6%%4\#t#L[<7:2(q%bLoUJ-ihFAZ8(okV$_2/3#eMZjVUCBY*$@#C8
f.g;'`(QbWlN/5ch23"UI.;!U]b]?.3bl"[D`ptgMPp`[]2kb>FS[rg+rT'GcIUFp
9Lm-$9:,R>W)].KT3GCc#ked"lsJr$SS-06!@MdMaX<\pZkm%n@JTKU)`DNb\om=[
cTR&hB$He;fOKuUo[6AoGOBkWp"-C\p0*osET9M5T6]Q:,@>`X'eGT7PuU[Y+`kiM
b7>XV(cEV(VUO)tG7%MK%McBF.U<8[Xbm<ARRAu-*P*?`,X=tPmHts)`/#!n9tJ;H
E"Q.R3V"mT,818(!="XEGk+MVVD\J'OY</e[q#:FX>M2rCZ3&t*hide5^``$"%!:C
%VIujr/hsA5@YX7>om,h(&Rfd5WUcgi]&9D@;ipZ[Yuo0&lMNdAu`gX8&GA^9Ud<Z
=.aoTrpT0AX\j(0J*BeVbFT`hi1,0"[oEcEHtHt;nf_aoi*k<EAYVbV-@%Y/)R;\4
e^`4FMQYnd3i`JtrU)VZrU=/9#UpZ.1%o"$e$P56W,(B+k/$4KbX4Gt`W"m%W>c$D
f?5h^*!]q\jtg,bM8H'Zp88@]m)g'A5Vk/N"=06jU37i),RF[J!\X`-n2u4H![H#Q
+-n6JR!@u`UWP<R!?jW*&oF!j9]X#]O4qi(nY/#E$0o[Ub$mU!=2=WkNZC3Y>,n8S
=8Z?SPY/Oq#Vk;EcTWk<$Pk:TSuYqr%d?*=IZh/A2W(acYuFIf<d4H-gCK0dUaT*2
U>;5MdBX^/\A=)e-;F'Um4;PSo]DW](.R:p&l_,!*e4*-D&]^U,tjQneSEd>^%9N2
U&*`'rcDQ*I^'Ls&/C;m(]6+@c2SAu4;A'n\^#'b=OGZL%HeB/.3VnX%'C<<M'nn1
RC4qgfJ(],^5_qQ>u)C^J[$+f>$Z6t7BtD;hKr$/50#$M.B5*$#:eXTC,F5"QPPS#
ad9r^hq`cIB7MAb28+o_/fH&K\#=fcnF.B)'59==e0q[dE8Wu<V6dRN51qBJFpNYT
V:%g@EpOkYm+o9thnFLl^\kBl>AbJ-i;CNL7O)g3]HP2(Ap)*^7D4#b&mh<^5tA:$
,Y43PB@!/dn0<uV@bYtec35IQ1!d^j$ce;M%o/G&k*g(EWMuj?A0S[,j[tdA+ROF6
bt'l,jW!=>V]UC4L9bjcjt03Z:)uA&Q_64ceYBV[;7J[sWbo^SRYZ=np81QR@PbLM
HL"9ah#tCl\Q$/Aqqa;Ho.r'6;2Sa.!>O^j6\gE%,f&PHoSD6\IN/n9E,p2;!L_A\
BgTmi!XZ(3%j;<fA6@cIl=h3am'qB7'&MTbLBh+0E)aGmmIZ(kMc+Tg-g&p85Ve(m
q8oHE'OI,!E>DFEZ_XBBn7,S=5NZKL,Yfhkk4G4MUSE9dMX%6Xb"DN%e#dt:mljK`
_iFHV?erDDqt@(n]#sfiP:)QQYk21sSm-*C7:<5TA]g7^RlBY9]Qc0kjCWIREn\!@
:Yd_T++O:q71*`BV8t`#)EW8hcPA,G>H?t@=PjMh)Dj[l\Eg<0>ZTpPU`2=7A/K-<
V;Si?IQL\(V+ZcH;l:fEVpf_^nDQ@kGH"`Z,ET:iJ,fK2j<+$8rVlcmX3mRgcn<V"
660KQT]1#:ODn0cm*<M(%YG"a^@[RXc5@f&&3*c)JIjd_XCW6DV(H-f(aU5F\_3^O
,2T`;\2`/YI=8d3+#%(f,3t!o*D3_Y`MnD&@iRm_!p!pZ>pfO#;lR.#+#@M&%+^h=
$Y[I(iA$a9-[Bu_k\*du"&Z,_=5"%iQBjO_X:^H9:)WZdcY%pD%N#j,:;fnMF`i4V
_$(YM$&W=^8nc.<8DBXpF'SQq(LB(Bk"J'0N,)IsqT&R;mER[Y4d__p=`'P^.AL6I
0er'`f*qt"2q)/[7Gks+@'6T4m+Sith01aNhg`E:9kZ!`%SKP_8q8L2OP=tW2CSr-
;QcTD+9e1RKRPs;'WIH>5H<!2#7`RK2IZt9ne_#hBalFDnA-^8U4[+PmbS%.._&h:
rjg&-%mPA]q]![=DG'h8B#rmP)5[uP.)k[9A&&cbO]uehr,sbJIW-OK66-,#^`SQr
/^MOhU_*psVu&7LNZC4RCtlDCKQ.1;K9Qd;BO>^4TjdXn>uo?L<KiW3?.6P$Q7C?q
0D<^@i>1M4Pn"fqW7n8OW[thsd3@pIWQjHi<GI?G%Z)2>"`+U:/*9/5V^qcEQZq??
#H6!YIV>^]WeOUtYc4ehNrp7UD1?9lm+ITWJYg6#6As]Fj,FnkcW&V)\m1o9F$CCl
/p-I4Z&U/Krf,9q=MObF+JmMDAe1lJ&Q3'D[G29<4*U`EKZ_^RW$GJ[%4%d?^rjp.
cY=8:`Xn.IraY;JT8t'WQ=q7PA$k`K]ShJg,\#B,C\\.>3'TXb*q0/Enh]f)MT7>T
\knff,>VkHac76(&i>?o>O0kB__=J(_MaWi>mu@Xh7IldZ3M1+\2]BNKJ]T&8I8ZQ
l.(PTEkcM@FUNd1c^6WHcHY%le>3)\&#PV<m]Ic4W8K4dKhQj4'j&20)XY-%XqOK2
U3FVhl__Zpf</G4OU?F,Zq>1HPuY%b6VX\j!`#'4+5_[&ImAg@A@H@t9H$t(%9Ioh
Rq0o\e##j,0L<V5[VXV0$N@`2;ZJ6Z&6A=3U?qE+Th`,g%Je/Fej*uPES*`.J,&hP
s7Q3Qb9IFh:4E;jbiposgj_N`PRRVdYYkU!3l@,C)O.D8K'Ukj,E^C1]mEs9.k@[5
]NfDb5OO6F;$9'C0^u20MKYe.Bk]#;&etjNi%Fd<NMi@o.S_#^bY.`&2/ALZXCsi$
!/gXH/jr)RI0u*(9cE_c9Xt+Jn;r5M2`FgDK8OjpI.0GjWo34`@d,4JoaRPm-"e,'
^$P*%#CQOHk7n&J>P6T24*L>]RKk+OccKh>-lVSsbK8;cM2:`7pV94.c7iZm8qR<W
i[Q81i5(&JaNV\M5o4-b+#[rfi*-[tH0(=$4dBUf2C=]To$[slc;rpq,&._m.%3k6
h1`F@phshZ?ki`-JYgqi%VN6UN3GZ>^A.7Hj2SPio.9jb[\p&@QDQT8$W>]bCH$l?
'EX&3+i.&4^rjjV#\efn3Eo<VJ.q9$f[rB'CMQ@4+u>5!><O>9P0go=lDlVLCY,^Z
++;WRa'YL\+ZoSM:HpGhDnYgE/.l;n^OEk0a<M;$,r\iWYH51,&qo&G3uq.%LK>9t
^G$./#.o3>JHoGG74eZ3='pB`2KAf%,tjOPkQ:cmb<r?u?I]Y2+*r1d`_H&;cXFh6
1UDGjk,B$co=C.8o&@@eh0KX`+Thq7'pVa`QBr@&7sr7thXD/V$Q<_hK[^TQ@V/`*
44]iZD][XNA/eX.-ZnNn!Qd8_F4[?GQ)5o",Nm:p9_mo3"Oh8Ue'<Sq&hG1S+52t,
Z'0E]o'_X#Ie@i*!lhGf6]GNk0bqQ6`<0
```

I'm not sure if I still need to like parse the data or encode it or is there a tool of some sort in php to render this type of response?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How do you "paste this data into a file"?
How exactly are you doing this?

Comment: I just edited and re-phrased the initial statment I made, but like what I said above, I just like paste the data into a text editor and save it as a pdf file.

Comment: where is the data coming from? are you opening a pdf in a text editor and copying it?

Comment: I am sorry, but is this a question about PHP?

Comment: @chiliNUT the data comes from a response for a project that I am working on and they just give me that data as a string or text.

Comment: Although.... I don't like how the huge block in the second half of the screenshot is formatted. It looks like your viewer may be adding line breaks? Which you then paste into the file, breaking it

Comment: @OlegDubas yup, I am kind of using PHP on my project and was finding a way to render this data into a pdf file

Comment: is it a response from calling a function in php? is it data in a file you were given? what php code do can you show?

Comment: @chiliNUT I wasn't given any file. I would say I am like doing fwrite of like different commands on a remote system, then when I do fread this would be the data that I would be receiving, and some few other data as their response to my query.

Comment: that description is way too vague. I'm not sure what the community can offer, but based off of that I know that I will not be able to offer any assistance.

Comment: @chiliNUT sorry about that, but that's I think would be the shortest explanation to what I did, I do fsockopen to a remote url to connect to the remote system then, do fwrite to send a bunch of commands to the remote system, then when I do fread this would be the response I am getting from them, and the other system was of like a third party application that's why I have no control on what their response would be.

Anyway thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've posted here is a small part of a PDF file indeed. What you have pasted here is the beginning of the file (which looks legal) and the first part of an XObject - which is PDF speak and is used to represent an image in this case. Two remarks if you want to do something useful with this file:

1) What you have here is only a very small part - you need the complete PDF file in order to do anything with it.

2) Line endings are important in PDF because the file format works with objects and a cross reference table at the end of the file that contains byte offsets for all objects. So if you screw up the line endings, none of the offsets are still going to work and you have yourself a broken PDF file. If you treat the incoming data as binary data and write it to a file unchanged, normally you should end up with a good PDF file (assuming they send you the complete file and not the fragment you're showing here).